# Correct way to read\write to a file: heavily used application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, protobuf-net

We have an heavily used .Net 3.5 application that reads "expensive to create" data and caches it. The application reads\writes files based on it not "being used by another process". If some other process is reading and writing to the file, then the application goes to sleep(for some time) and retries. Is this a correct way of reading and writing files? Please advise.

```
public void Add<T>(string key, CacheItem<T> item)
        {
            bool fileInUse = false;
            while (!fileInUse)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(cachePath, key+".bin"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(stream, item);
                    }
                    fileInUse = true;
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message.Contains("being used by another process"))
                    {
                        //Poll till the file is free to be used by this process
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        fileInUse = false;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }        

public CacheItem<T> Get<T>(string key, Type type)
        {
            CacheItem<T> item = null;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(cachePath, key+".bin"));
            fileInfo.Refresh();
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                bool fileInUse = false;
                while (!fileInUse)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                        {
                            object objectTemp = Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(type, stream);
                            item = (CacheItem<T>)objectTemp;
                        }
                        fileInUse = true;
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex) 
                    {
                        if (ex.Message.Contains("being used by another process"))
                        {
                            //Poll till the file is free to be used by this process
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                            fileInUse = false;
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }                       
            return item;                                   
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a **global** mutex on top of it, to avoid waiting more than absolutely necessary.

Global mutex is created by passing a non-empty `name` to [Mutex Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx).

Benefits:

- Mutex will allow you to wake up immediately after the file becomes available, instead of waiting 50 ms on average.
- Mutex allows you to fall asleep **once** and wake up **once**, instead of repeatedly sleeping/waking. Threads that are sleeping are handled very efficiently by the OS and consume almost no resources at all.
- Once you acquire the mutex, the file open is almost 100% likely to succeed, instead of failing potentially many times before succeeding.

All in all, you are not just going to be *faster*, you'll likely consume *less CPU cycles* in the process.

Comment: @PankajGarg I'm sure I could, but what would that accomplish? Is there anything unclear as to how this mechanism would work?

Comment: Branko; 
Here is what one of our architects states=> "The reservations that I have with using the Mutex class is that it is computationally expensive than using the lock statement or Monitor class defeating the purpose of our performance enhancements." Any thoughts?

Comment: @AjitGoel It is, but it can synchronize **separate** processes, which Monitor cannot do. Also, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different design altogether if this is something you're doing a lot of (and therefore performance is an issue).

You should have a public static method (or a method in a singleton) that takes a string (and a filename if this works with multiple files).  In that method it should place that string into a `BlockingCollection<string>`.  (You can have just one, or one per file through a `Dictionary<string, BlockingCollection<string>>` that maps filenames to the queue for that file.)

In the majority of cases (i.e. the buffer isn't full) the tasks that want to write something to a file just add it to a queue and then get right back to working.

You then need to have a separate thread/task that just sits there reading from the blocking collection(s) (you should only need one, even if you have lots of blocking collections) and writing the data out to a file.  Since there is only one thread writing to the files there is no locking that needs to go around the file IO, and `BlockingCollection` is designed to work in this producer/consumer model and takes care of all the needed locking for you.

I would suggest using just a single `BlockingColleciton` for all files unless you find a compelling performance reason to try to deal with multiple queues.  It'll be quite a bit easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks Servy. I had forgotten to add that our application is a .Net 3.5 application. BlockingCollection are a part of .Net 4.0.

Comment: @AjitGoel You can do everything with `ConcurrentQueue` instead.  It's a little less convenient, but you can.

Comment: ConcurrentQueue is .Net 4.0 and above? I cannot use in our application.

Comment: @AjitGoel Hm...I could have sworn ConcurrentQueue was 3.5.  Guess not.  Oh, well, just use a `Queue` and put `lock` statements anything that accesses it, it'll be good enough.